# Ошибка при использовании сервиса ASP.NET Core/

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Учусь использовать ASP.NET Core, дошел до темы внедрения зависимостей. Вот какая ошибка вылезла при компиляции:
[image: Вот]

Весь код:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IGreetings, EnGreetings>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<MyService>();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.Map("/hello", app =>
{
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        var met = context.RequestServices.GetService<MyService>();
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<h1>{met?.Meetings()}</h1>");
    });
});

app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Lalalalalalalal");
});

app.Run();

public interface IGreetings
{
    public string PrintHello();
}

public class RuGreetings: IGreetings
{
    public string PrintHello()
    {
        return "Привет мир!";
    }
}

public class EnGreetings: IGreetings
{
    public string PrintHello()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    private IGreetings _greetings;
    private string _name;
    

    public MyService(IGreetings greetings, string name)
    {
        _greetings = greetings;
        _name = name;
    }

    public string Meetings()
    {
        return $"Hey, {_name}\n{_greetings.PrintHello()}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Представьте, что у вас есть магическая корзина, в которую вы запихнули описание объекта, а на их основе она вам по требованию отдает уже объект, да не просто объект, она еще и в него внедрит все, что требует сам этот объект, выбрав из того, что вы ей ранее запихнули. Вот это зовется контейнером, где вы в него регистрируете типы (`.Services.AddTransient<MyService>();`), а он вам по требованию (`.GetService<MyService>()`) этот тип создает. Теперь внимание, создает он из того, что уже есть в нем. И вот вы просите некий `string name`, у него это есть? Нет. Вот он и выдал вам ошибку.

Comment: То есть, в вашем случае, вы просите у контейнера нечто, чего он не может вам дать. И тут возникает вопрос - а должно это быть у данного объекта, или нет? Я думаю, что нет. Ну а если вам всеж такое надо, то надо указывать этот `string` при регистрации (один из [примеров](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50831752/6808809)), либо оборачивать все в фабрику.